# Locking and List Protection

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I'm very interested to hear how you would solve similar functionality or issues you see with how I've implemented the following solution:

We have a server application that will be running a large number of threads at any given time. This app was written in unmanaged code and will be hosting various .net assemblies. That said any of these running threads may want access to the Cache below, either Account data or User data in my example. I'm trying to limit my usage of locking, therefore you can see my attempt to read from either List(s), account or user, to see if the item exist before lock and cache it to the corresponding collection. Also you can see below i'm using SingleOrDefault() which will throw an exception if more than 1 item is returned and that's exactly what's happening.  For some reason I simply cannot re-create getting duplicates in the code I've provided below but I believe it to be a locking issue. I've put in a couple Thread.Sleep()s to simulate some deviations in performance.  My general questions are the following:

1. Do you see any issue with having a local lock object inside the Account class to protect the users collection? I choose have a specific locker for the specific collection in question.
2. Does that pattern I've implemented make sense to you or would you have solved this problem entirely differently?
3. Overall I'm interested in your own experience and solution on this subject.

Thanks,
-mike

```
    internal class Program
    {
    private const int UpperLimit = 5;
    private static readonly string[] Users = {"mike", "dave", "john", "alex", "steve", "joe"};
    private static readonly string[] Accounts = {"100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600"};
    private static readonly Random Rnd = new Random();

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            var t = new Thread(ThreadEntry);
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static bool IsOdd(int value)
    {
        return value%2 != 0;
    }
    private static void ThreadEntry()
    {
        var accountId = Accounts[Rnd.Next(UpperLimit)];
        var username = Users[Rnd.Next(UpperLimit)];

        if (IsOdd(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
        {
            var acct = Cache.GetAccount(accountId);
            Console.WriteLine("Thread : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId +
                              " is accessing cache for account " + acct.AccountId);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Thread : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " is accessing cache for user : " +
                          username + " in Account : " + accountId);
        var user = Cache.GetUser(accountId, username);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " has obtained user : " + username);
    }
    }
    public static class Cache
     {
    private static readonly object AccountsLock = new object();
    private static readonly List<Account> _accountList = new List<Account>();
    private static readonly Random Sleeper = new Random();

    public static User GetUser(string accountId, string name)
    {
        var acct = GetAccount(accountId);
        return acct.GetUser(name);
    }
    public static Account GetAccount(string accountId)
    {
        // attempt to quickly retreive account without locking out other threads
        var acct = _accountList.SingleOrDefault(p => p.AccountId == accountId);
        Thread.Sleep(Sleeper.Next(1000));
        if (acct == null)
            acct = CacheAccount(accountId); // account doesn't exist and needs to be cached

        return acct;
        }
        private static Account CacheAccount(string accountId)
        {
        lock (AccountsLock)
        {
            // previous read from accounts list was without lock. Check again to see if account exist / possibly added by another thread.
            var acct = _accountList.SingleOrDefault(p => p.AccountId == accountId);
            if (acct == null)
            {
                acct = new Account(accountId);
                _accountList.Add(acct); // add new account to the cache
            }
            return acct;
        }
       }
    }
    public class Account
    {
    private static readonly Random Sleeper = new Random();
    private readonly List<User> _userList = new List<User>();
    private readonly object _usersLock = new object();
    public string AccountId;

    public Account(string accountId)
    {
        AccountId = accountId;
    }
    public User GetUser(string name)
    {
        // attempt to quickly retreive user without locking out other threads
        var user = _userList.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == name);
        if (user == null)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(Sleeper.Next(750));
            user = CacheUser(name); // account doesn't exist and needs to be cached
        }

        return user;
    }
    private User CacheUser(string name)
    {
        lock (_usersLock)
        {
            // previous read from users list was without lock. Check again to see if user exist / possibly added by another thread.
            var user = _userList.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == name);
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new User(name);
                _userList.Add(user); // add new user to the cache
            }
            return user;
        }
    }
    }
    public class User
    {
    public string Name;

    public User(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    }
```

Comment: You might consider using a `ConcurrentBag<T>`, which is thread-safe by design, instead of `List<T>`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The question is far too broad. That said, in general you can improve performance with locking that is more fine-grained, i.e. having more specific locking as you seem to be describing here. As far as the cache specifically goes, a dictionary is a often a good choice for caches, and the .NET `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` provides a good, thread-safe implementation you can use.